# Wordpress: onSelect not Working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, onselect

I have been trying to display value of a datepicker in a div and two texboxes. I was able to do it in a normal PHP file however when i try to do it in a wordpress website. It is not happening The jquery code i am using is as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {
         jQuery('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker({
             altField: '#wc_order_field_2563', //setting alternate field
             onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    $('#show_pickupdate_input').val(dateText);
                    $('#pickupdate_text').text(dateText);
                 //alert(dateText);
                }
         });
    });
```

If you want to see this in action you an see it on [twomoms.kitchen](http://twomoms.kitchen) checkout page. However this does not seem to work no matter what I do.

Please let me know what is it that i am doing wrong :(

Comment: you mind to add `datepucker` library to your page.

Answer (score 0):

the issue got resolved by changing the code above with the following code below. This modification was done as the datepicker was added using a plugin that adds any fields as required. Code below changes div and textbox using the change in other textbox.

```
jQuery(function() {
         jQuery('#wc_order_field_2563').datepicker({
             onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    $('#show_pickupdate_input').val(dateText);
                    $('#pickupdate_text').text(dateText);
                 //alert(dateText);
                }
         });
    });
```